# TF.exe label - Workspace mapping required when creating a label for a server item?

Tags: tfs

In my TFS release i added a script to create a label when a certain environment succeeds.

This label is apply on a given server item and for a specific Changeset.

The TF.exe command looks like this:

tf.exe label Main-Approved $/MyProject/Main /recursive /version:C124730 /comment:"Approved by Main Release" /collection:http://tfsserver:port/tfs/MyCollection

However when run from the release i get the following error message return by TF.exe:
Error: There is no working folder mapping for D:\Agent-Default_work\r144\a\by.

Running this exact command localy works fine and creates the label.

I don't understand why i would need to create a workspace and some folder mapping in order to apply a label on a **Server** item (using $/...) for a specific changeset?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i was using a Python script to run the command.

I tried changing it to a powershell script and it works.

My guess is that in python the strings were passed incorrectly someone. I feel like the workspace 'by' was in fact my command wrongly parsed by the intepreter and considered an argument in tf.exe.